# getInitialMessage && getInitialMessage not working flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup firebase in my app,
i create onBackgroundMessageHundler in the top level,
onMessage I received the message
but on getInitialMessage && getInitialMessage not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i solved the problem thank you

Comment: Dear @Yassine dev, kindly note that am facing the same issue, can you please provide your answer, what you did to solve the issue??

Comment: you have to put the onBackgroundMessageHundler on the top of your app, if you can post the code i can see what is your problem exactly